# set of custom icons drag and drop in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

so far what i have is a map that place the bar's location according to the street address given by the user.

But now i need to associate an icon describing the type of bar that the user's have. So i have a list of icons at the right of my map and the marker inside the map.

Is there any way to drag and drop the image chosen by the user and have this marker replaced by the new image?

The idea is to capture the icon that is beeing dragged, have the current marker replaced by this new one, and store the info into my database. I think i can do the last part but i dont have much knowledge of the first two parts :(

any guide on how to start would be very much appreciated :)

Comment: so far this is what i have, i actually made a good progress :) i will answer my own question with the code :)

Answer (score 4):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>MVC is Fun</title>

        <style type="text/css">
            *{
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
            }
            html { height: 100% }
            body{ height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}
            #map_canvas { height: 50% }
            #shelf{position:fixed; top:10px; left:500px; height:100px;width:200px;background:white;opacity:0.7;}
            #draggable {position:absolute; top:10px; left:10px; width: 30px; height: 30px;z-index:1000000000;}
        </style>
        <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#draggable").draggable({helper: 'clone',
                    stop: function(e) {
                        var point=new google.maps.Point(e.pageX,e.pageY);
                        var ll=overlay.getProjection().fromContainerPixelToLatLng(point);
                        var icon = $(this).attr('src');
                        placeMarker(ll, icon);
                    }
                });
                $("#draggable2").draggable({helper: 'clone',
                    stop: function(e) {
                        var point=new google.maps.Point(e.pageX,e.pageY);
                        var ll=overlay.getProjection().fromContainerPixelToLatLng(point);
                        var icon = $(this).attr('src');
                        placeMarker(ll, icon);
                    }
                });
                $("#draggable3").draggable({helper: 'clone',
                    stop: function(e) {
                        var point=new google.maps.Point(e.pageX,e.pageY);
                        var ll=overlay.getProjection().fromContainerPixelToLatLng(point);
                        var icon = $(this).attr('src');
                        placeMarker(ll, icon);
                    }
                });
                $("#draggable4").draggable({helper: 'clone',
                    stop: function(e) {
                        var point=new google.maps.Point(e.pageX,e.pageY);
                        var ll=overlay.getProjection().fromContainerPixelToLatLng(point);
                        var icon = $(this).attr('src');
                        placeMarker(ll, icon);
                    }
                });
                $("#draggable5").draggable({helper: 'clone',
                    stop: function(e) {
                        var point=new google.maps.Point(e.pageX,e.pageY);
                        var ll=overlay.getProjection().fromContainerPixelToLatLng(point);
                        var icon = $(this).attr('src');
                        placeMarker(ll, icon);
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var $map;
            var $latlng;
            var overlay;
            function initialize() {
                var $latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(66.5, 25.733333);
                var myOptions = {
                    zoom: 3,
                    center: $latlng,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    mapTypeControlOptions: {
                        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU,
                        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT },
                    zoomControl: true,
                    zoomControlOptions: {
                        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
                        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
                    },
                    scaleControl: true,
                    scaleControlOptions: {
                        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
                    },
                    streetViewControl: false,

                    panControl:false,

                };
                $map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                myOptions);

                overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
                overlay.draw = function() {};
                overlay.setMap($map);
            } 
            function placeMarker(location, icon) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: location, 
                    map: $map,
                    icon: icon
                });

            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="initialize()">
        <div id="map_canvas"></div>
        <div id='shelf'>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <img src="ico_beer.png" id="draggable" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="ico_comedy.png" id="draggable2" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="ico_dance_club.png" id="draggable3" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="ico_food.png" id="draggable4" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="ico_karaoke.png" id="draggable5" />
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="info"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

of course i have used this guy's answered question wich helped me a lot! :)
[google maps drag and drop objects into google maps from outside the Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510972/google-maps-drag-and-drop-objects-into-google-maps-from-outside-the-map)